# How to remove escape character from the output of Lookup activity in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am reading JSON data from SQL Database in Azure Data Factory.
I have Azure Data Factory (ADF) pipeline, contains "Lookup" activity, which reads the JSON Data from SQL DB and bring into ADF Pipeline. Somehow the escape character (" \ ") get inserted in JSON data when I see at the output of Lookup activity of ADF.

For Example, the output of Lookup activity become like this:
{\ "resourceType\ ":\ "Sales","id" :\ "9i5W6tp-JTd-24252\ "

Any idea how to remove the escape character from JSON in pipeline?

Update:

Thanks for the update Joseph. When I try your steps, It doesn't work for me.

1. In lookup am reading data from SQL DB.

[image]

2. This is my Append variable:

[image]

After running it, I still see escape character

```
{
    "firstRow": {
        "JSONData": "{\"resourceType\":\"counter\",\"id\":\"9i5W6tp-JTd- and more
```

Comment: So you want to convert `{"resourceType":"Sales","id":"9i5W6tp-JTd-24252"}` to `{"resourceType":Sales,"id":9i5W6tp-JTd-24252}`,like this?

Comment: Actually the output of lookup activity is like this:
 "{\ "resourceType\":\ "Sales\",\ "id\ ":\ "9i5W6tp-JTd-24252\ "}

And I want to remove all escape character and output should be like this:
{"resourceType":"Sales","id":"9i5W6tp-JTd-24252"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we know, '\' is an escape character. In your case, this symbol appears because it is used to escape one double quote inside a pair of double quotes.
For example, "\"" => """.

But it doesn't matter, we only need to convert it from string type to json type, it will automatically remove escape characters.
I've created a test to verify it.

1. First, I defined an Array type variable.
   [image]
2. My Lookup activity's output is as follows:
   [image]
3. Then I used an AppendVariable activity and used an expression `@json(activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.value)` to convert it from string type to json type.
   [image]
4. After I run debug, we can see the result as follows, there is no '\'.
   [image]

Comment: hi  Dinesh Madhup,  I am also using SQL query to get the data from database. I'm using a sql query `DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @json = N'[
  {"id": 2, "info": {"name": "John", "surname": "Smith"}, "age": 25},
  {"id": 5, "info": {"name": "Jane", "surname": "Smith"}, "dob": "2005-11-04T12:00:00"}
]';

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json)`. It will return a json string.

Comment: Please see my post. I tried same steps, except SQL Query. Does SQL QUERY matter?

Comment: Actually It works when I use @json(activity('Lookup2').output.firstRow.JSONData)
But I only need value. Don't wanna see "variableName": "Object". That's why I was intended to use :
@json(activity('Lookup2').output.value). 
Whats the difference?

Comment: This expression is determined based on the structure of the output, not the same.

Comment: Hi Joseph,
I can see how things get broken. If my query has more than 1 rows then it fail. For example:
SELECT TOP(2)
 JSONData
FROM StgFHIR
WHERE ISJSON(JSONData) > 0

In this case we can't use firstRow in this line: @json(activity('Lookup2').output.firstRow.JSONData

So, how can use more than 1 rows in Lookup?

Comment: If your query has more than 1 rows, you must Re-update the expression at AppendVariable activity. Because there is not property named **firstRow**, you should remove it.

Comment: I removed firstRow  from expression. Used this: @json(activity('Lookup2').output.JSONData)

Then getting error on Append variable:

Details
The expression 'json(activity('Lookup2').output.JSONData)' cannot be evaluated because property 'JSONData' doesn't exist, available properties are 'count, value, effectiveIntegrationRuntime, billingReference, durationInQueue'.

Comment: I see. Append variable activity is used to add one object at once. If you're trying to add an Array to it, it got error. You should use a Foreach activity to foreach the array. Inside the Foreach activity, we can use Append variable.

Comment: There is only one way. Using Foreach activity. It will be a little complex, can you ask another question about how to remove escape character at an json string array .

Comment: OK. I connect Lookup to ForEach. In ForEach  setting I put Items as @variables('Object').
Inside ForEach I put Append variable and Variable value I put as @json(item())

When i DEBUG Append variable not get called.

Comment: I have another thread open for that:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64713152/how-to-remove-escape-character-at-an-json-string-array

Comment: Thank you Joseph. Appreciated!

Comment: Hi @Dinesh Madhup You're welcome. I ran another test, it works well and I've post the answer.