# How to remove escape character at an JSON string array?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory

In Azure Data Factory, I have Lookup activity. "Lookup" activity, which reads the JSON Data from SQL DB (more than 1 row) and bring into ADF Pipeline.

The lookup activity output contains escape character. Please see this:

```
 {\ "resourceType\ ":\ "counter","id" :\ "9i5W6tp-JTd-24252\ "
```

How to remove escape character? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: By the way, since the `json` function only supports string types instead of array types, we have to do more complicated work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your query result is an JSON String array, we need to do more to remove escape character.

Here is my steps:

1. Firstly, we can define two array type variables.
   [image]
2. Here is the summary, the Lookup activity will return an JSON String array.
   [image]
   Here is the output of my Lookup activity.The data structure will affect the following expression at the Append variable inside the Foreach activity.
   [image]
3. At the ForEach activity we can use `@activity('Lookup1').output.value` to get the JSON String array.
   [image]
4. Inside the ForEach activity, we can use `@json(item().value)` to get the one object of the JSON String array and remove escape character.
   [image]
5. In the end, we can use a SetVariable activity to check the result.
   [image]

After I run debug. We can see the correct result:
[image]

Comment: Append variable causing issue in my case. I think, based on my data structure as below:
{
    "count": 2,
    "value": [
        {
            "JSONData": "{\"resourceType\":\"counter\",\"id\


I should replace @json(item().value) with @json(item().JSONData)
What do you say?

Comment: No, please use  `@json(item().value)`.  This is the fixed output of the Lookup activity.

Comment: When I use @json(item().value) then Append variable giving me this error:

The expression 'json(item().value)' cannot be evaluated because property 'value' doesn't exist, available properties are 'JSONData'.

It has value there. Don't know why say that

Comment: I'm very sorry, you are right! I am a little messy. Please use `@json(item().JSONData) `.