# Using a variable in the Request Body form in Azure Data Factory Copy Data activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

Is it possible to use a variable in the "Request body" field in a Copy data activity?

This is my pipeline:

[image]

Output of "Get requestBody":

[image]

Allready full of unwanted slashes.

Output of "Set variable":

[image]

I using this expression in the "Request body" Field:

```
@replace(variables('requestBody'),'\','')
```

[image]

This is the input of "Copy data":

[image]

I cant get rid of all slashes. Is it even possible to use a variable for "Request body"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the backslashes, I had to use this:

```
@replace(string(variables('requestBody')), '\"', '"')
```

Answer (score 1):

As your `lookup` activity output returns **JSON** string value it includes an **escape** **character** backslash **'\'**.

To remove the escape character, create an array type variable and convert the lookup out to JSON array in `append variable` activity as below.

1. Create **array** variable.

[image]

2. **Lookup** output: As I checked firstrow only property in lookup activity, the output results firstrow only.

[image]

3. In the `Append variable` activity, get the lookup output and convert it to JSON array.

`@json(activity('Lookup1').output.firstrow.requestbody)`

[image]

4. Append variable result: Use this variable in later activities.

[image]

You can refer to these [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64713152/how-to-remove-escape-character-at-an-json-string-array) & [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64707802/how-to-remove-escape-character-from-the-output-of-lookup-activity-in-azure-data) threads for reference.

Comment: I get this error now: `cannot be parsed: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing number: @. Path 'reportRequests[0].pageSize', line 1, position 469`  Because I have this in my variable: `@{if(equals(variables('NextPageToken'),'-1'),'',concat(',\"pageToken\":\"',variables('NextPageToken'),'\"')`

Comment: I removed the part that is causing problems, but still, the backslashes aren't gone: `"requestMethod": "POST",
        "requestBody": "[{\"reportRequests\":[{\"viewId\":\"239894743\",\"dateRanges\"` etc. The backslashes come back if I convert the JSON to String. I need the JSON stuff as a string without the escape characters.

Comment: Hi, are you seeing this escape character in input or output of your activity?

Comment: I see them on the output of Lookup and on the input of Set Variable etc. But I got it working. The solution was to use `@replace(string(variables('requestBody')), '\"', '"')`