# Passing list to ADF

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I have a python function that returns a list of items as a string as part of an ADF pipeline using

```
some_list = ["Thing1", "Thing2", "Thing3"]

return_string = '","'.join(some_list)

return func.HttpResponse(return_string)
```

When ADF picks this up, it is littered with escape characters:

```
"\"Thing1\",\"Thing2\",\"Thing3\""
```

How can I get this list out?

Comment: Have you tried changing the mime type of your response, using the `mimetype` argument [refer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-functions/azure.functions.httpresponse?view=azure-python)

Comment: ```some_list = list(map(lambda x: '"' + x + '"', some_list))

return_string = ','.join(some_list)```  this gives you the comma separated literals correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Convert string type to json type, This will remove escape character.

Use `@json(activity('Python Function').output)` expression.

[image]

I have used expression in Append Variable activity.

[image]

You can also refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64710730) by joseph-xu