# How to encapsulate all the JSON rows in one JSON columns in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Hi I am getting the data from the odbc connection in csv format then I am copying it to Blob with json dataset
It will look something like this not the actual data it will have more than 20K rows

```
{"A":12345,"B":"2023-12-31 00:00:00","C":5510,"D":20231231,"E":20240103,"F":20231231,"G":1577158,"H":63217,"I":null,"J":"Company123","K":"SupplierXYZ","L":"987","M":"Vendor ABC","N":"Invoice789","O":"2023-12-31T00:00:00","P":"2024-01-03T00:00:00","Q":"2023033344","R":"7559","S":"Dept123","T":"ModelXYZ","U":7179.0,"V":3,"W":"3769686.0","X":"TypeJ","Y":7179.0,"Z":null,"AA":"NOK","AB":"202312.0","AC":"EXTERNAL","AD":null,"AE":"Counterparty999","AF":"2023-12-31T00:00:00","AG":null,"AH":null,"AI":"66c6c4cc31107992a4079f3653a8a86930a2675d8663c5ab2ec4df23b0f6f3b0","AJ":"2024-02-13T12:58:02.597","AK":"2024-01-03T08:31:16.425292"}
{"A":54321,"B":"2024-01-15 08:00:00","C":7890,"D":20240115,"E":20240120,"F":20240115,"G":2468135,"H":951753,"I":null,"J":"Company456","K":"Supplier789","L":"123456789","M":"Vendor XYZ","N":"Invoice123","O":"2024-01-15T08:00:00","P":"2024-01-20T08:00:00","Q":"2024011515","R":"1234","S":"Dept456","T":"ModelABC","U":9876.0,"V":6,"W":"9876543.0","X":"TypeK","Y":9876.0,"Z":null,"AA":"USD","AB":"202401.0","AC":"INTERNAL","AD":null,"AE":"Counterparty888","AF":"2024-01-15T08:00:00","AG":null,"AH":null,"AI":"a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9","AJ":"2024-02-15T08:00:00.123","AK":"2024-01-20T08:00:00.987654"}
```

Now I want the final result to be like this after transformation.

```
{
    "Id": "a parameter",
    "Name": uuid;
    "data": Json array from the source
}
```

I need to encapsulate all the Json rows into this data column. After this I can feed this to API using a web activity
So how should I transform this data in the dataflow.

Comment: What will be the value for Id and Name? How are you getting those data?

Comment: So Id is added as a parameter. It's a fixed value. and name needs to be generated from guid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **lookup activity** to read the Json file and take copy activity to add additional columns id, name along with Json data. Below is the approach.

- Take the lookup activity and take the Json file as delimited dataset. Give the delimiter differently so that all data will be in the single row.

[image]

- Take the copy activity and connect it in sequence with the first lookup activity.
- In source dataset, take a dummy dataset with one row. Add additional columns in source settings.

[image]

1. id: give the parameter name here
2. data: `@json(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].Prop_0)`
3. Name: `@guid()`

- In the mapping section, map only the required three columns. Delete all the remaining columns.
  [image]
- Add the sink dataset.
- Run the pipeline and sink dataset will be as required.

[image]

**This approach is applicable to Json data with not more than 4MB**.  Refer the [supported capabilities of lookup activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity#supported-capabilities).

If your data is more than 4MB, dataflow is the only option to do the requirement.

- Take the source transformation. Take the same source dataset that you took in the lookup activity of the first approach.
- Take the derived column transformation and new additional columns id, name and data.
  [image]

**Dataflow approach:**

- Take the select transformation and select only the above three columns.
- Take the sink transformation with sink Json dataset.
- Run the pipeline with the dataflow and sink Json will be as required.

Comment: Thanks for the approach. Just one question. Is it possible to remove this slashes \ from the data column

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Check the [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64707802/how-to-remove-escape-character-from-the-output-of-lookup-activity-in-azure-data). You need to use `@json()` .

Comment: I'll check it Thanks. But I do have one last question. Is there a limit that it can encapsulate only this much amount of data. So my input file has 249826 rows. and after doing what you have suggested still, I am having 2608 rows in the output file. after a certain amount of data, it is creating a new row. and not necessarily the data start with the starting column that is "A" It start from where the first row ended suppose it has ended at c then new row will have {Id: "", name:"", Data :{"D":"","E":""}} Do you understand what I am trying to say.

Comment: There could be limitations in that. I have not tried with such huge data. Is it possible to concat them for you

Comment: Hi, the previous issue is resolved. But when I am copying it to the rest API. I am getting valid json array. I checked the Api documentation. the data should be -
Array of objects
A valid JSON list where every row is an object. Each element of list should be a flattened object (e.g. no nested objects).

Comment: Can you ask a new question in this platform with more details.

Comment: Provide the sample data also for better understanding

Comment: I have posted another question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78205483/how-to-convert-the-json-string-to-the-array-and-remove-the-escape-characters

Comment: Checking that .