# how to convert the Json string to the array and remove the escape characters

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

This is my input file - It is just a sample It will have more than 20k rows

```json
{"A":12345,"B":"2023-12-31 00:00:00","C":5510,"D":20231231,"E":20240103,"F":20231231,"G":1577158,"H":63217,"I":null,"J":"Company123","K":"SupplierXYZ","L":"987","M":"Vendor ABC","N":"Invoice789","O":"2023-12-31T00:00:00","P":"2024-01-03T00:00:00","Q":"2023033344","R":"7559","S":"Dept123","T":"ModelXYZ","U":7179.0,"V":3,"W":"3769686.0","X":"TypeJ","Y":7179.0,"Z":null,"AA":"NOK","AB":"202312.0","AC":"EXTERNAL","AD":null,"AE":"Counterparty999","AF":"2023-12-31T00:00:00","AG":null,"AH":null,"AI":"66c6c4cc31107992a4079f3653a8a86930a2675d8663c5ab2ec4df23b0f6f3b0","AJ":"2024-02-13T12:58:02.597","AK":"2024-01-03T08:31:16.425292"}
{"A":54321,"B":"2024-01-15 08:00:00","C":7890,"D":20240115,"E":20240120,"F":20240115,"G":2468135,"H":951753,"I":null,"J":"Company456","K":"Supplier789","L":"123456789","M":"Vendor XYZ","N":"Invoice123","O":"2024-01-15T08:00:00","P":"2024-01-20T08:00:00","Q":"2024011515","R":"1234","S":"Dept456","T":"ModelABC","U":9876.0,"V":6,"W":"9876543.0","X":"TypeK","Y":9876.0,"Z":null,"AA":"USD","AB":"202401.0","AC":"INTERNAL","AD":null,"AE":"Counterparty888","AF":"2024-01-15T08:00:00","AG":null,"AH":null,"AI":"a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9","AJ":"2024-02-15T08:00:00.123","AK":"2024-01-20T08:00:00.987654"}
```

I want the output as

```json
{
"dataRepositoryId": "fixedvalue",
"importName": "uuid,
"data": [
{"A":12345,"B":"2023-12-31 00:00:00","C":5510,"D":20231231,"E":20240103,"F":20231231,"G":1577158,"H":63217,"I":null,"J":"Company123","K":"SupplierXYZ","L":"987","M":"Vendor ABC","N":"Invoice789","O":"2023-12-31T00:00:00","P":"2024-01-03T00:00:00","Q":"2023033344","R":"7559","S":"Dept123","T":"ModelXYZ","U":7179.0,"V":3,"W":"3769686.0","X":"TypeJ","Y":7179.0,"Z":null,"AA":"NOK","AB":"202312.0","AC":"EXTERNAL","AD":null,"AE":"Counterparty999","AF":"2023-12-31T00:00:00","AG":null,"AH":null,"AI":"66c6c4cc31107992a4079f3653a8a86930a2675d8663c5ab2ec4df23b0f6f3b0","AJ":"2024-02-13T12:58:02.597","AK":"2024-01-03T08:31:16.425292"},
{"A":54321,"B":"2024-01-15 08:00:00","C":7890,"D":20240115,"E":20240120,"F":20240115,"G":2468135,"H":951753,"I":null,"J":"Company456","K":"Supplier789","L":"123456789","M":"Vendor XYZ","N":"Invoice123","O":"2024-01-15T08:00:00","P":"2024-01-20T08:00:00","Q":"2024011515","R":"1234","S":"Dept456","T":"ModelABC","U":9876.0,"V":6,"W":"9876543.0","X":"TypeK","Y":9876.0,"Z":null,"AA":"USD","AB":"202401.0","AC":"INTERNAL","AD":null,"AE":"Counterparty888","AF":"2024-01-15T08:00:00","AG":null,"AH":null,"AI":"a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9","AJ":"2024-02-15T08:00:00.123","AK":"2024-01-20T08:00:00.987654"}
]}
```

the input file should be encapsulated in the data column
I have read the input file through a csv dataset and gave delimeter as ^ so that it can read it as one column and then used a derived column and used data as [Inputcolumn] but my final data is looking like this

```json
{"dataRepositoryId": "fixed vale","importName": "uuid","data":"[\"{\\\"A\\\":12345,\\\"B\\\":\\\"2023-12-31 00:00:00\\\",\\\"C\\\":5510,\\\"D\\\":20231231,\\\"E\\\":20240103,\\\"F\\\":20231231,\\\"G\\\":1577158,\\\"H\\\":63217,\\\"I\\\":null,\\\"J\\\":\\\"Company123\\\",\\\"K\\\":\\\"SupplierXYZ\\\",\\\"L\\\":\\\"987\\\",\\\"M\\\":\\\"Vendor ABC\\\",\\\"N\\\":\\\"Invoice789\\\",\\\"O\\\":\\\"2023-12-31T00:00:00\\\",\\\"P\\\":\\\"2024-01-03T00:00:00\\\",\\\"Q\\\":\\\"2023033344\\\",\\\"R\\\":\\\"7559\\\",\\\"S\\\":\\\"Dept123\\\",\\\"T\\\":\\\"ModelXYZ\\\",\\\"U\\\":7179.0,\\\"V\\\":3,\\\"W\\\":\\\"3769686.0\\\",\\\"X\\\":\\\"TypeJ\\\",\\\"Y\\\":7179.0,\\\"Z\\\":null,\\\"AA\\\":\\\"NOK\\\",\\\"AB\\\":\\\"202312.0\\\",\\\"AC\\\":\\\"EXTERNAL\\\",\\\"AD\\\":null,\\\"AE\\\":\\\"Counterparty999\\\",\\\"AF\\\":\\\"2023-12-31T00:00:00\\\",\\\"AG\\\":null,\\\"AH\\\":null,\\\"AI\\\":\\\"66c6c4cc31107992a4079f3653a8a86930a2675d8663c5ab2ec4df23b0f6f3b0\\\",\\\"AJ\\\":\\\"2024-02-13T12:58:02.597\\\",\\\"AK\\\":\\\"2024-01-03T08:31:16.425292\\\"}\\\n", "{\\\"A\\\":54321,\\\"B\\\":\\\"2024-01-15 08:00:00\\\",\\\"C\\\":7890,\\\"D\\\":20240115,\\\"E\\\":20240120,\\\"F\\\":20240115,\\\"G\\\":2468135,\\\"H\\\":951753,\\\"I\\\":null,\\\"J\\\":\\\"Company456\\\",\\\"K\\\":\\\"Supplier789\\\",\\\"L\\\":\\\"123456789\\\",\\\"M\\\":\\\"Vendor XYZ\\\",\\\"N\\\":\\\"Invoice123\\\",\\\"O\\\":\\\"2024-01-15T08:00:00\\\",\\\"P\\\":\\\"2024-01-20T08:00:00\\\",\\\"Q\\\":\\\"2024011515\\\",\\\"R\\\":\\\"1234\\\",\\\"S\\\":\\\"Dept456\\\",\\\"T\\\":\\\"ModelABC\\\",\\\"U\\\":9876.0,\\\"V\\\":6,\\\"W\\\":\\\"9876543.0\\\",\\\"X\\\":\\\"TypeK\\\",\\\"Y\\\":9876.0,\\\"Z\\\":null,\\\"AA\\\":\\\"USD\\\",\\\"AB\\\":\\\"202401.0\\\",\\\"AC\\\":\\\"INTERNAL\\\",\\\"AD\\\":null,\\\"AE\\\":\\\"Counterparty888\\\",\\\"AF\\\":\\\"2024-01-15T08:00:00\\\",\\\"AG\\\":null,\\\"AH\\\":null,\\\"AI\\\":\\\"a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9\\\",\\\"AJ\\\":\\\"2024-02-15T08:00:00.123\\\",\\\"AK\\\":\\\"2024-01-20T08:00:00.987654\\\"}\\n\"]"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to convert the Json string to the array and remove the escape characters

As you are taking Json rows in CSV file when you are pushing it to Json file the dataflow considering whole thing as string, and you are getting backslashes as escape characters.

- My data sample:
  [image]
- As you know the schema you need to parse it as Json format using below expression

```json
(A as string,       B as date,      C as integer,       D as integer,       E as integer,       F as integer,       G as integer,       H as integer,       I as integer,       J as string,        K as string,        L as string,        M as string,        N as string,        O as string,        P as string,        Q as string,        R as string,        S as string,        T as string,        U as double,        V as integer,       W as string,        X as string,        Y as double,        Z as string,        AA as string,       AB as string,       AC as string,       AD as string,       AE as string,       AF as string,       AG as string,       AH as string,       AI as string,       AJ as string,       AK as string)
```

[image]

- Then Take derived column and create an dummy column with value 1.
  [image]
- Then take aggregate function to create data array:
  [image]
  [image]
- Then take another derived column transformation to create another columns.
  [image]
- Then take select transformation and select only required column.
  [image]
- Then add sink and Json file where you need output.
  [image]

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: check the data type you have given is correct or not.

Comment: I got the mistake. Thanks for the approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try using derived column as json(Inputcolumn) will help.

Json() function will convert the string into json output.

Also you can use replace('\\\','') it will works and generate output like this

```json
["{"A":12345,"B":"2023-12-31 00:00:00","C":5510,"D":20231231,"E":20240103,"F":20231231,"G":1577158,"H":63217,"I":null,"J":"Company123","K":"SupplierXYZ","L":"987","M":"Vendor ABC","N":"Invoice789","O":"2023-12-31T00:00:00","P":"2024-01-03T00:00:00","Q":"2023033344","R":"7559","S":"Dept123","T":"ModelXYZ","U":7179.0,"V":3,"W":"3769686.0","X":"TypeJ","Y":7179.0,"Z":null,"AA":"NOK","AB":"202312.0","AC":"EXTERNAL","AD":null,"AE":"Counterparty999","AF":"2023-12-31T00:00:00","AG":null,"AH":null,"AI":"66c6c4cc31107992a4079f3653a8a86930a2675d8663c5ab2ec4df23b0f6f3b0","AJ":"2024-02-13T12:58:02.597","AK":"2024-01-03T08:31:16.425292"}n", "{"A":54321,"B":"2024-01-15 08:00:00","C":7890,"D":20240115,"E":20240120,"F":20240115,"G":2468135,"H":951753,"I":null,"J":"Company456","K":"Supplier789","L":"123456789","M":"Vendor XYZ","N":"Invoice123","O":"2024-01-15T08:00:00","P":"2024-01-20T08:00:00","Q":"2024011515","R":"1234","S":"Dept456","T":"ModelABC","U":9876.0,"V":6,"W":"9876543.0","X":"TypeK","Y":9876.0,"Z":null,"AA":"USD","AB":"202401.0","AC":"INTERNAL","AD":null,"AE":"Counterparty888","AF":"2024-01-15T08:00:00","AG":null,"AH":null,"AI":"a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9","AJ":"2024-02-15T08:00:00.123","AK":"2024-01-20T08:00:00.987654"}"]
```